# Reset single values on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, calculation

I have a form with two options. The user can choose to fill option a and add option b. A sum of all the filled inputs is calculated at the end. I use a show hide function to show the fields of option b.

What I try to achieve if it's possible is when the user choose both options, fill them and get the result, if they choose to change back to option a, to remove the values of the option b and update the calculation automatically.

```js
$("#option-b").click(function() {
  $(".va3, .va4").show();
});
$("#option-a").click(function() {
  $(".va3, .va4").hide();
});

calculate = function() {
  var optiona1, optiona2, optiona3, optiona4, resultss;
  optiona1 = Number(document.getElementById("a1").value);
  optiona2 = Number(document.getElementById("a2").value);
  optiona3 = Number(document.getElementById("a3").value);
  optiona4 = Number(document.getElementById("a4").value);
  if (a3 == null || a3 == "", a4 == null || a4 == "") {
    resultss = parseInt(optiona1) + parseInt(optiona2);
  } else {
    resultss = parseInt(optiona1) + parseInt(optiona2) + parseInt(optiona3) + parseInt(optiona4);
  }
  document.getElementById('a5').value = resultss;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="option-a" onclick="document.getElementById('a3, a4').value = '0'">option a</button>
<button id="option-b">option b</button><br>
<label>Option a price 1:</label><input id="a1" type="text" /><br>
<label>Option a price 2:</label><input id="a2" type="text" /><br>
<label class="va3" style="display: none">Option b price 1:<input id="a3" type="text" /></label><br>
<label class="va4" style="display: none">Option b price 2:<input id="a4" type="text"  /></label><br>
<label>Result:</label><input id="a5" type="text" onfocus="calculate()" name="total_amt" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest keeping the `option-a` and `option-b` as checkboxes or radio buttons.

Checkboxes if both can be selected [OR] radio buttons if only 1 can be selected at a time.

And add a button for calculation. Clicking on the button does the calculation.

```
<label for="option-a">Option A</label> 
<input id="option-a" type="checkbox" name="option" value="a" />
<label for="option-b">Option B</label>
<input id="option-b" type="checkbox" name="option" value="b" />

<label class="va1" style="display: none">Option a price 1:<input id="a1" type="number" /></label><br>
<label class="va2" style="display: none">Option a price 2:<input id="a2" type="number"/></label><br>
<label class="va3" style="display: none">Option b price 1:<input id="a3" type="number" /></label><br>
<label class="va4" style="display: none">Option b price 2:<input id="a4" type="number"  /></label><br>

<label>Result:</label><input id="a5" type="text" name="total_amt" />
```

Then implement a 'change' listener which does the following.

```
$('input[name="option"]').on('change', function(e){
 const isChecked = $(e.target).is(":checked");
 const optionValue = $(e.target).val();
 if(optionValue == "a" && isChecked){
  $(".va1, .va2").show();
  $("#a1")[0].value = ""
  $("#a2")[0].value = ""
 }else if(optionValue == "b" && isChecked){
  $(".va3, .va4").show();
  $("#a3")[0].value = ""
  $("#a4")[0].value = ""
 } else if(optionValue == "a" && !isChecked){
  $(".va1, .va2").hide();
  $("#a1")[0].value = "";
  $("#a2")[0].value = ""
 } else if(optionValue == "b" && !isChecked){
  $(".va3, .va4").hide();
  $("#a3")[0].value = ""
  $("#a4")[0].value = ""
 }
});
```

Then implement a `focusout` event for the input text fields. This will make sure that the calculate is called, whenever the input number changes.

```
$('input[type=number]').on('focusout', calculate);
```

Here is the working fiddle link

> http://jsfiddle.net/jmhuwby1/

Comment: I tried, but this doesn't work. I can't even show and hide the options. And will it solve the problem of updating the result?

Comment: When option-a is selected, the code resets the value of a3 and a4 using `$(".a3").val("");`. Is this what you mean by "updating the result"?
What do you mean by doesn't work. Can you share the specific error / screenshot?

Comment: Sure, I tried to add what you suggested, and here's what it gives http://jsfiddle.net/g9ke0ovs/3/

Comment: Hi, I have modified the fiddle to make it work. Please check now.

Comment: Here is the updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/je8v94kw/

Comment: Thank you. Isn't it possible to have the result without the button result? I mean, if at first I check both options, fill all the fields with 20. The result would be 80. And then I decid to uncheck option b, the result would update to 40 automatically.

Comment: Yes. It's possible. Trigger the calculate function call within the change event of the checkbox.

Comment: If it works, can you help with two things? 1. Upvote the answer. 2. Mark the answer as correct.

Comment: Yeah, but how can I trigger the calculate function call within the change event of the checkbox, it was the main purpose of my question actually.

Comment: Updated with changes here - http://jsfiddle.net/jmhuwby1/